SharePoint Server 2013 : All site pages error
Kindly need your help on this matters.

This error occurs only on one of my site collection.
All pages have same error including site content and site setting page.
Do not have logs. (Its not configured)

Kindly suggest any step to troubleshoot and solve this issue.


It's usually something wrong with a (custom) master page. Did you change the master page of this site collection?

Thanks for the idea. But i just find out it was because the issue on the access mapping and its resolved when fixed on it.

Look at Technical details and correlation ID seem to log file.

Run SharePoint configuration wizard, can it be executed successfully?
